# Understanding two lines from a proof that successor cardinals are regular

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, cardinals

I would appreciate help checking my thinking and understanding regarding the following two relations from a proof that: For every ordinal $\alpha$, the successor cardinal $\aleph_{\alpha}^{+}$ is regular.

If $S\subseteq\aleph_{\alpha}^{+}$ is cofinal ($\alpha$ is any ordinal)

1) $\aleph_{\alpha}^{+} = \bigcup_{\beta\in S}\beta$

I think that since $S$ is cofinal, then for every $x\in\aleph_{\alpha}^{+}$, there is a $y\in S$ such that $x\leq y$. Thus the union of the elements of $S$ is equal to $\aleph_{\alpha}^{+}$

2) $\aleph_{\alpha}^{+} \leq \sum_{\beta\in S} |\beta|$

I could see this if the summands were $\beta$'s; then the RHS would be an upper bound. Where I am confused is that for every ordinal $\beta$, the cardinality $|\beta|\leq \beta$. So how do you know 2) holds?

Thanks

Comment: By $\bigcup_{\beta\in S}$ you probably meant $\bigcup S=\bigcup\{\beta\mid \beta\in S\}$. In any case, just writing $\bigcup_{\beta\in S}$ is notationally incorrect.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thanks - I'm hopeless; can't even copy.

Comment: For 2), find an injection from $\aleph_{\alpha^+}$ into $\bigsqcup\{|\beta|:\beta\in S\}=\bigcup\{|\beta|\times\{\beta\}:\beta\in S\}$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo May I please ask what $|\beta|\times{\beta}$ means. Is it the cardinality $|\beta|$ indexed by $\beta$ as an ordinal?

Comment: Sure, but it is $|\beta|\times\{\beta\}$ rather than $|\beta|\times\beta $.

Comment: Do you understand that if $X=\bigcup X_i$, then $|X|\leq \sum |X_i|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are almost correct. $S$ is cofinal, so - as you've noted - for
   every $\gamma \in \aleph_{\alpha}^{+}$ there is some $\sigma \in S$
   such that $\gamma \leq \sigma$. Since $\aleph_{\alpha}^{+}$ is a limit ordinal we get a slighly better result (replacing $\gamma$ with $\gamma+1$): For $\gamma \in \aleph_{\alpha}^{+}$ there is some $\sigma \in S$
   such that $\gamma +1 \leq \sigma$, i.e. $\gamma \in \sigma$. This now immediately implies (using the transitivity of ordinals) that
   $$
   \bigcup S = \aleph_{\alpha}^{+}.
   $$
2. We need to find an injection
   $$
   f \colon \aleph_{\alpha}^{+} \to \sum_{\sigma \in S} | \sigma |.
   $$
   For each $\gamma \in \aleph_{\alpha}^{+}$ let $\sigma(\gamma)$ be the least $\sigma \in S$ such that $\gamma +1 \le \sigma$. (Such a $\sigma$ exists by our remark above). Furthermore fix, for each $\sigma \in S$, a bijection
   $$
   \pi_{\sigma} \colon \sigma \to | \sigma |.
   $$
   (Why is this possible?)
   Now recall that $\sum_{\sigma \in S} | \sigma | = \bigcup_{\sigma \in S} | \sigma | \times \{\sigma \}$ - the disjoint union of all $| \sigma |$. So, for each $\gamma \in \aleph_{\alpha}^{+}$, $f(\gamma)$ is of the form
   $$
   f(\gamma) = (i, \sigma),
   $$
   where $\sigma \in S$ is suitable and $i \in |\sigma| = \operatorname{ran}(\pi_{\sigma})$. (What is a suitable $\sigma$ and how could we choose $i \in | \sigma|$) to make $f$ into an injection? [Hint: Make use of $\sigma(\gamma)$ and $\pi_{\sigma(\gamma)}$.])

Comment: I'm very confident that you'll be able to merge these elaborated hints into a full proof.

Comment: Thanks (+1) for your kind answer. Please forgive me as I have to go out for a bit and will give it the attention it deserves when I come back.

Comment: No worries. I'll head to bed soon but will be happy to answer any additional questions tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks you again. May I ask a few follow-up questions: The purpose of an injection to the disjoint $|\sigma|$'s is to show that the enumeration of the LHS of 2) is $\leq$ the RHS. Also is $\pi_{\sigma}$ really a bijection since for any infinite ordinal (I think) the cardinality of $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{+}$ are the same. Lastly, (since your answer is so kindly explicitly detailed) in that $\aleph^{+}_{\alpha}$ is well-ordered, to make $f$ into an injection, I would take the cardinality of $\sigma(\gamma)$ indexed by each $\sigma(\gamma)$. Best regards,

Comment: For each $\sigma$ there is an bijection $\pi_{\sigma} \colon \sigma \to |\sigma|$ - just by the definition of a cardinal. The cardinality of $\sigma$ is the least ordinal $\delta$ such that there is a bijection $\sigma \to \delta$. We then need the axiom of choice to not only pick one such bijection $\pi_{\sigma}$ but a whole sequence $(\pi_{\sigma} \mid \sigma \in S)$.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the last part of your comment but $f(y) = (\pi_{\sigma(\gamma)}(\gamma), \sigma(\gamma))$ is what I had in mind. This will give an injection - basically by diagonalizing all the bijections $\pi_{\sigma}$, $\sigma \in S$.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: Dear Stefan - You probably know I am a self-studier. I just went through this great answer again, and really understood and appreciate it all the more so. Thanks,

Comment: @Andrew I'm happy I could help :-)